# Kendo UI MVC Grid with inline editing combobox. "Undefined" error even with template null check?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo MVC UI Grid with inline editing successfully as shown in the code below. My issue came to be when I added a ComboBox field (as an editor template).

When I create a new row, the grid evaluates my Client Template (showing the dependant property's 'name' attribute). I have added a conditional check for null, but this doesn't seem to matter. Removing the Client Template causes this to work fine,

In the conditional, I am checking for PointOfContact == null, however when I add a new record via inline editing I immediately get "PointOfContact is not defined", so the null check isn't really doing anything for me.

**Razor View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Blag.Models.Site>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    //Name  MailingAddress  City    State   Zip     Country     POC     
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).ClientTemplate("<a href='Sites/details/#=ID#'>#=Name#</a>");
    columns.Bound(p => p.MailingAddress);
    columns.Bound(p => p.City);
    columns.Bound(p => p.State);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Zip).Width("7em");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Country);
    columns.Bound(p => p.PointOfContactID).EditorTemplateName("POCDropDown").Title("POC").ClientTemplate(
    "# if (PointOfContact != null) { #" + //This seems to be screwing things up
    "#: PointOfContact.Name #"+   //note, no matter what I put here, this doesn't affect crash
    "# } else { #" +
    "  None " +
    "# } #");
    columns.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Edit();
    });
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:90%;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
    .Create(update => update.Action("Grid_Create", "Sites"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "Sites").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Grid_Update", "Sites"))
    //   .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
    )
)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function error_handler(e) {
            if (e.errors) {
                var message = "Errors:\n";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function() {
                            message += this + "\n";
                        });
                    }
                });
                alert(message);
            }
        }

    </script>
```

**Razor Editor Template **

```
         @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                .Name("PointOfContactID")
                .DataValueField("ID")
                .Filter("contains")
                .DataTextField("Name")
                .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("JSON", "POCS").Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 40em;" })
          .HeaderTemplate("<div class=\"combobox\">" +
                        "<span class=\"k-widget k-header\">Name</span>" +
                        "<span class=\"k-widget k-header\">Email</span>" +
                "<span class=\"k-widget k-header\">Phone</span>" +
                    "</div>")
  .Template("<div class='combobox'><span class=\"k-state-default\">#:data.Name#</span><span class=\"k-state-default\">#:data.Email#</span><span class=\"k-state-default\">#:data.Phone#</span></div>")
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up the default value for `PointOfContact` in the model

```
.Model({model => model.Id(p => p.ID); model.Field(d => d.PointOfContactID).DefaultValue(new PointOfContact()); })
```

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't realized I did not have PointOfContact instantiated in my client-side implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Hope this is useful to somebody.

For some reason a new record throws an error on this particular client template, however if I check for another primitive value such as:

```
   columns.Bound(p => p.PointOfContactID).EditorTemplateName("POCDropDown").Title("POC").ClientTemplate(
    "# if(Name && PointOfContact) { #" +
    "#:PointOfContact.Name#"+
    "# } else { #" +
    "  None" +
    "# } #");
```

This works great with no apparent side effects. I think this is because my JS doesn't have a column for PointOfContact directly so the client object doesn't know anything about it.

Actually, it makes alot of sense when looked at it that way!